# Add Border for merged rows and columns in HSSFCellStyle not working in Windows

Tags: java, excel, hssf

I generated an excel sheet, applied styles and added border for each cell.

```
style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
```

In case of Merged cells(both rows and columns) the above code is working fine in Unix, but in Windows, the style is getting applied only for the first of two merged cells.